# What is the order of packets in TCP sender buffer and why are the packets in receiver buffer not continuous?

Tags: tcp

The scenario is about the the sliding window on TCP level. The left side of image blew is sender buffer(filled with the blank and the light blue areas), then right side is receiver buffer. As we know the data which we want transmit should be cut in several packets and they are marked in sequence ready for transmission. However, I doubts about following problems.

1. Why is the **order** of packets in sender buffer, are the packets in order of the seq number?

> (What I mean is that should the packages sender buffer keeps in order by the marked sequence number? or out-of-order?)

2. Why the packets in receiver buffer are not continuous, when could this happen? The picture blew is the sender buffer(**left**) and receiver buffer(**right**) of a tcp connection.

> (What I means is that are the packets receiver receives and stores in buffer in order by packets sequence number? if yes, does it mean the buffer makes it easier for packets reassemble?)

---

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The image might have been helpful but the reference is broken (at least for users which are not logged into gitee.com).

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, thanks for your reminding, the image is available now .

Comment: The question is still not clear since it is missing essential context. What send and receive buffer you are talking about anyway (for the specific socket)? Is this image specific for some selected TCP stack or in general ...

Comment: I added some context more for explaining my question, hope it's clearer. Sorry for the trivia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not much context available in your question and it is unclear where this image comes from. But I assume that the image refers to the sockets send and receive buffer in the kernel.

Since the applications sends continuous data on the socket and the data are send in the given order to the peer by the kernel all the still unsent data in the send buffer are in order. Note that this assumes that no optimizations are done by the system if [SACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retransmission_(data_networks)) is enabled.

Contrary to this the kernel has no control in which order the data get received and it might happen that later data (higher sequence number) gets received earlier then previous data, since the previous data were lost or due to reordering in transit. Thus there might be gaps in the received data which will hopefully be filled once the outstanding data are received.

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. Here is my understanding, please correct it if necessary. The buffer keeps the seats for the previous packets which have not been received. And even the higher sequence number packets have arrived, receiver won't give the ACK based on higher sequence number packets to sender until the reversed seats for lower sequence number packets arrived. Otherwise,once  the sender gets the higher sequence number packets ACK, then assert the packets send before all have been received correctly. This mechanism guarantees the correctness and security.